# office 365 excel csv hyperlink not displaying correctly when imported to excel

Tags: excel, csv

Office 365 Pro current version.
I created a column in a csv file that is formatted as a hyperlink

```
"=HYPERLINK(""https://xxxxx.xxxxxxx.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""|""SAM SMITH"")"
```

when imported to excel I replaced "= with = and changed the column format to hyperlink.  The HYPERLINK is formatted correctly but does not display correctly.  If I click on the formula icon and open the formula dialog and then close the formula dialog.  Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: a macro is required to convert the hyperlink to a url: http://jerryleventer.com/excel-tutorial-how-to-convert-plain-text-links-into-hyperlinks/

Comment: Still having trouble activating the formula in excel  the code at the link above Public Sub Convert_To_Hyperlinks()
    Dim Cell As Range
    For Each Cell In Intersect(Selection, ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
        If Cell <> "" Then
            ActiveSheetHyperlinks.Add Cell, Cell.Value
        End If
    Next
End Sub didn't work and I've tried a couple variations without success.  If I edit and enter on the column it displays correctly.